# How to start a service in linux after running command not at start of the system?

Tags: linux, command-line, services

I have created a servicefile and I kept it in the /etc/systemd/system.
It is starting the service as a daemon at the start of the system.
I don't want it to start at the start of the system.
I want to start the service when I will run a command to start the service.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Extract from the Debian `systemd` [documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd#Managing_services)*

Show status of the service "example1":

```
systemctl status example1
```

Enables "example1" to be started on bootup:

```
systemctl enable example1
```

Disable "example1" to not start during bootup:

```
systemctl disable example1
```

Start a Service example1

```
systemctl start example1
```